# How to manually upgrade libc6?

Tags: glibc

I have a live linux distro, taken from [this](https://www.phenix.bnl.gov/~purschke/RescueCD/) article. My working linux is Ubuntu 14 x64 where I build the live distro. I need to add an application to distro, so I copied executable to `bin` folder, chrooted distro root folder and after running new application I got the message that:

```
bash-4.2# pv
pv: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by pv)
pv: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by pv)
```

I have just copied `libc.so.6` from my Ubuntu (which has 2.19) to /lib64 folder in distro root. But then I got an error

```
bash-4.2# pv
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 743: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
```

So my guess is that I have to copy more files and I am looking for some list which files to copy. This is what I have in lib dir.

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 1000 1000     4096 Aug 26 16:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 1000 1000     4096 Jan 26  2013 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 Dec  8  2011 dhcpcd
drwxr-xr-x 22 1000 1000     4096 Feb 11  2013 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 Jan  9  2006 grub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   132520 Jan 19  2013 ld-2.13.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   132520 Jan 19  2013 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   117748 Jan 19  2013 ld-linux.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1285552 Jan 19  2013 libX11.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14312 Jan 19  2013 libXau.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       17 Aug 24 14:08 libXdmcp.so.6 -> libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    22472 Dec  8  2011 libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    73544 Jan 19  2013 libXext.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    22696 Jan 19  2013 libXv.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    35208 Jan 19  2013 libacl.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    18568 Jan 19  2013 libattr.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   983760 Jan 19  2013 libbfd-2.21.1.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   143088 Jan 19  2013 libblkid.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       15 Aug 24 14:08 libbz2.so.1 -> libbz2.so.1.0.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       15 Aug 24 14:08 libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    66736 Dec  8  2011 libbz2.so.1.0.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1563856 Jan 19  2013 libc-2.13.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1563856 Jan 19  2013 libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       17 Aug 24 14:08 libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14464 Nov 19  2011 libcom_err.so.2.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       17 Aug 24 14:08 libcrack.so.2 -> libcrack.so.2.8.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    39200 Dec  8  2011 libcrack.so.2.8.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    34912 Jan 19  2013 libcrypt.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1587384 Jan 19  2013 libcrypto.so.0.9.8
-r-xr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1699360 Jan 19  2013 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1515608 Dec  8  2011 libdb-4.8.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       12 Aug 24 14:08 libdb.so -> libdb-4.8.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       15 Aug 24 14:08 libdbi.so -> libdbi.so.0.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       15 Aug 24 14:08 libdbi.so.0 -> libdbi.so.0.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    60088 Oct 11  2009 libdbi.so.0.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14512 Jan 19  2013 libdl-2.13.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14512 Jan 19  2013 libdl.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       13 Aug 24 14:08 libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    27920 Nov 19  2011 libe2p.so.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    22656 Jan 23  2013 libeinfo.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       21 Aug 24 14:08 libevent-2.0.so.5 -> libevent-2.0.so.5.1.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   275488 Jan 19  2013 libevent-2.0.so.5.1.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    18632 Jan 19  2013 libevtlog.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   165864 Jan 19  2013 libexpat.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       16 Aug 24 14:08 libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   197528 Nov 19  2011 libext2fs.so.2.4
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000    88256 Jan 19  2013 libgcc_s.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1155920 Jan 19  2013 libglib-2.0.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14400 Jan 19  2013 libgmodule-2.0.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000     5920 Jan 19  2013 libgthread-2.0.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000 18276992 Jan 19  2013 libicudata.so.48
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1430144 Jan 19  2013 libicuuc.so.48
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000      527 Feb  9  2013 libip4tc.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    26624 Feb  9  2013 libip4tc.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000      527 Feb  9  2013 libip6tc.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    30752 Feb  9  2013 libip6tc.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000      525 Feb  9  2013 libipq.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000      526 Feb  9  2013 libiptc.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    56112 Jan 19  2013 liblber-2.4.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   260416 Jan 19  2013 libldap-2.4.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   526456 Jan 19  2013 libm.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   113672 Jan 19  2013 libmagic.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   333648 Jan 19  2013 libncurses.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   333648 Jan 19  2013 libncurses.so.5.9
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   383152 Jan 19  2013 libncursesw.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       20 Aug 24 14:08 libnfsidmap.so -> libnfsidmap.so.0.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       20 Aug 24 14:08 libnfsidmap.so.0 -> libnfsidmap.so.0.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    26720 Jan 19  2013 libnfsidmap.so.0.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    88872 Dec 11  2011 libnsl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       14 Aug 24 14:08 libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       13 Aug 24 14:08 libnss3.so -> libnss3.so.12
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1246896 Nov 19  2011 libnss3.so.12
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       18 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_compat.so -> libnss_compat.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    31432 Jan 19  2013 libnss_compat.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       15 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_dns.so -> libnss_dns.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    22736 Feb 22  2013 libnss_dns.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    47440 Jan 19  2013 libnss_files-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       17 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_files.so -> libnss_files.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    47440 Jan 19  2013 libnss_files.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       18 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_hesiod.so -> libnss_hesiod.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    18672 Jan 19  2013 libnss_hesiod.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    35664 Jan  9  2009 libnss_mdns-0.2.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       18 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_mdns.so.2 -> libnss_mdns-0.2.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       15 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_nis.so -> libnss_nis.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    43368 Jan 19  2013 libnss_nis.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       19 Aug 24 14:08 libnss_nisplus.so -> libnss_nisplus.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    51504 Jan 19  2013 libnss_nisplus.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       16 Aug 24 14:08 libnssckbi.so -> libnssckbi.so.12
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   562488 Nov 19  2011 libnssckbi.so.12
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       16 Aug 24 14:08 libnssdbm3.so -> libnssdbm3.so.12
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   158544 Nov 19  2011 libnssdbm3.so.12
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       19 Aug 24 14:08 libnsssysinit.so -> libnsssysinit.so.12
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    10136 Nov 19  2011 libnsssysinit.so.12
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       17 Aug 24 14:08 libnssutil3.so -> libnssutil3.so.12
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   125704 Nov 19  2011 libnssutil3.so.12
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    51608 Jan 19  2013 libpam.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    51608 Jan 19  2013 libpam.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14392 Jan 19  2013 libpam_misc.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14392 Jan 19  2013 libpam_misc.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    14392 Jan 19  2013 libpamc.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   277456 Jan 19  2013 libparted.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   229256 Jan 19  2013 libpcap.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    48192 Jan 19  2013 libpci.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   239672 Jan 19  2013 libpcre.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    48080 Jan 19  2013 libpopt.so.0
-r-xr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    64224 Jan 19  2013 libproc-3.2.8.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   131256 Jan 19  2013 libpthread.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       10 Aug 24 14:08 librc.so -> librc.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    47456 Dec 26  2011 librc.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   275672 Jan 19  2013 libreadline.so.6
-r-xr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   275672 Jan 19  2013 libreadline.so.6.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    80528 Jan 19  2013 libresolv.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    35656 Jan 19  2013 librt.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    27000 Jan 19  2013 libss.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   338832 Jan 19  2013 libssl.so.0.9.8
-r-xr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   373216 Jan 19  2013 libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   970448 Jan 19  2013 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   433744 Jan 19  2013 libsyslog-ng.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   143184 Jan 19  2013 libtirpc.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    51600 Jan 19  2013 libusb-1.0.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    10464 Jan 19  2013 libutil.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000      526 Jan 19  2013 libuuid.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       16 Aug 24 14:08 libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    18776 Nov 19  2011 libuuid.so.1.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    33904 Jan 19  2013 libwrap.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   117344 Jan 19  2013 libxcb.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000  1335680 Jan 19  2013 libxml2.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000      529 Feb  9  2013 libxtables.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    47688 Feb  9  2013 libxtables.so.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000    92504 Jan 19  2013 libz.so.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 Feb 11  2013 modules
drwxr-xr-x  4 1000 1000     4096 Jan 23  2013 rc
drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 Dec 26  2011 security
drwxr-xr-x  6 1000 1000     4096 Feb 11  2013 udev
```

UPD1: alternatively I've downloaded GLIBC 2.19 source code, compiled and copied libs into distro's lib dir. Now I got another error when I chroot:

```
sudo chroot root_tree64/
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "I have just copied libc.so.6 from my Ubuntu (which has 2.19) to /lib64 folder in distro root." You really, really don't want to do that. It will break your system. "I need to add an application to distro". What application is that? Can you rebuild it on your machine?

Comment: It's Pipe Viewer. That is what I did - rebuilt from source code on my machine and copied to distro's bin folder.

Comment: And is still gives those error messages about GLIBC? Can you add a linkt to Pipe Viewer in case anyone wants to look at it?

Comment: Here is the link to pv http://sourceforge.net/projects/pipeviewer/ and I updated my post with new attempt

Comment: When rebuilding the software from source, it would normally link against the version of libc6 you are using. Are you saying it doesn't?

Comment: It does of course, but my distro's libc was older than it required. Updating only `libc.so.6` was not enough as I realized due to dependencies. Now I tried to updated whole GLIBC package, but still no positive results.

Comment: Software doesn't usually depend on a particular version of lib6. Is this documented in the source code?

Comment: Not that I met in documentation, but you can see in my post's first lines what I got after running pv in chrooted distro.

Comment: I just built it myself. I don't see any specific libc dependency. What commands did you use to build it? Give complete steps, including what files you downloaded, and if you untarred stuff, give those steps too.

Comment: `./configure --prefix=$HOME/a --exec-prefix=$HOME/b; make; make install` It does work on my Ubuntu as well, but it doesn't work in chrooted environment of distro that I mentioned.

Comment: That's strange. What is the result on ldd run in a chrooted environment?